# HTTP error 414 returning from the payment gateway

Tags: http

I have a setback I hope you can help me
the following happens
I'm doing a test of the payment gateway of my website and what happens is that once inside the checking (or about to make the payment) when I go back it sends me back to the page to finalize the purchase (so far so good) .
the problem is that it seems that when doing that some options on the page disappear and when trying to go to the home page
I get an error 414 for URl too long.

and I can not access the page again until I exit the browser clear cache and reopen

I know that this can be solved by modifying the Apache httpd configuration, however it seems to me that it is not correct.

I use Wordpress with Woocommerce and CoinPayments gateway

I do not put my web address because I do not know if it is allowed by the forum, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414), another potential cause could be a redirect loop. Are there any entries in your server log indicating problems?

Comment: The latest server error messages I have received are as follows: [Fri Jan 22 12:10:01.862836 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 500389:tid 47734934107904] [client 200.80.43.109:34690] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/ingresos/public_html/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/, referer: https://www.ingresos2.uno/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/